# iOS - how to handle online/offline data

Tags: ios, database, core-data

I am currently developing an app with a big database. Think of the app as similar to TripAdvisor in the following way: multiple cities with different databases, each between 5, 10, 20, 30 MBs. My whole app is based on this data: every view needs some part of it.

I'm having big trouble finding the correct way to handle this huge chunk of data. I am currently using CoreData: I think it is a great tool, and for offline mode, it definitely works great.
The problem is, I can't really combine it with "online" mode. If the user doesn't want to store the data for X/Y reason, I'm not sure how I should handle the data.
Simply allocate it in variables that will be released anyway, or is there a better way to handle the data?
Right now I am stocking it into CoreData without saving it: I know this is absolutely not a good way to manage it. How could I achieve this?
What is the best way to handle online data and then simply stock it if the user wants it offline too?

Comment: Your question is very confusing.  If the user doesn't download the data, then how is it on the device to begin with?  Everything after "The problem is" seems contradictory and does not make any sense to me.  Maybe reformulate your question with some more information, or be more precise about what it is you want to achieve.

Comment: I understand my question is confusing, sorry about that. I meant the user doesn't store the data, of course he downloads it. I think that was the big difference. The point is that some users will want to store the data on their phone for offline usage, and others won't (not enough memory, etc). There lies my problem. How can I handle those two different stockage methods?

Comment: You could conditionally use an in-memory store or a file store for the persistent store coordinator (you can even use both at the same time).  Of course, you will run the risk of eating all the memory if you allow too many objects to exist in the store at any one time, but I assume you already have a way of limiting the number of objects if the user is working in this mode.

Answer (score 0):

**Option 1:**

Data is always static/ not change data frequently:
You should have data on online. You can fetch data by **webservice** and store it to local database(i.e core -data). For example: Bible, Quran app.

**Option 2:**

Data change frequently and user need to update frequently:same as above. Additionally, from server you send notification(i,e push-notification) to app that server has a new data.After getting notification in app, download and save data to you database.