# How to design the offline data for iPhone/iPad to search data

Tags: ios, iphone, database, ipad, core-data

I'm developing an app which fetches huge data from webserver (for example data stored in flipkart). This works fine when I want to search any data online.
Now I need to enable searching of data in offline mode also. So how do I achieve this? 
As per below link, storing data in local database does not seem to be good idea.

[iOS - how to handle online/offline data](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33106673/ios-how-to-handle-online-offline-data)

Any optimised way to deal with this scenario?

Comment: If you want to search when you are offline, then the data needs to be on the local device in some form.  If you only have a summary of the data on the device then the user will need to go online to retrieve the actual item.  You haven't given any information on what you want to search and your question is too broad.

Comment: If you want to manage offline then you have to store data in local!

Comment: Why does local database not seem like a good idea? It is exactly what I would do. You can always mix the core data with fetching data directly.

Comment: @MaticOblak - when database is very huge(for example database of any online shopping like Amazon ), in that case i think local database does not seem to be better option.

Comment: @sia Better option then what? If you want this to work offline you need to have the data locally. So the only answer to that I see is Not a better option then storing raw responses. Which is probably not true, database should be better even if it means storing JSON data in it.

Comment: @MaticOblak - I'm not sure what better option but you may be correct on your point.

Comment: @sia You need to download all that data in order to search for it offline. But as Paulw11 already mentioned if database is too large then just download a shell that you need for searching (like saving only name and id for each object). This might significantly reduce the size of the data you have but again as mentioned if you then need a detail version of any of these objects you will need to download it. Think of it as if a searchable list would work offline but when user presses an item on the list a new screen appears with loading indicator and starts by downloading that object by its ID.

Comment: @MaticOblak - you are correct and i can try Paulw11  approach also.